# Generate Time Sequence for Trading Hours

Tags: r, time-series

I would like to create a sequence where I generate points at 9:30am and 4:00pm starting from Sys.time() to a specified end date.

```
#So for example if:
end.date = 2019-04-12 
Sys.time() = 2019-04-10 12:00 #the sequence should look like this.

2019-04-10 12:00
2019-04-10 16:00
2019-04-11 09:30
2019-04-11 16:00
2019-04-12 09:30
2019-04-12 16:00

#The goal is to put it into a function where the output would be :

x = function(Sys.time(), end.date)
print(x)
 2019-04-10 12:00
 2019-04-10 16:00
 2019-04-11 09:30
 2019-04-11 16:00
 2019-04-12 09:30
 2019-04-12 16:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create a function using `outer`

```
get_date_time <- function(start.date, end.date, times) {
  c(outer(seq(as.Date(start.date), as.Date(end.date), by = "1 day"), 
  times, paste, sep = " "))
}

get_date_time("2019-04-10","2019-04-12",c("09:30:00", "16:30:00"))

#[1] "2019-04-10 09:30:00" "2019-04-11 09:30:00" "2019-04-12 09:30:00" 
#[4] "2019-04-10 16:30:00" "2019-04-11 16:30:00" "2019-04-12 16:30:00"
```

The above returns output in character format. If you need a date-time object and also the order of values is important we can use `as.POSIXct` and `sort` them.

```
get_date_time <- function(start.date, end.date, times) {
   sort(as.POSIXct(outer(seq(as.Date(start.date), as.Date(end.date), by = "1 day"), 
   times, paste, sep = " ")))
}

#[1] "2019-04-10 09:30:00 +08" "2019-04-10 16:30:00 +08" "2019-04-11 09:30:00 +08" 
#[4] "2019-04-11 16:30:00 +08" "2019-04-12 09:30:00 +08" "2019-04-12 16:30:00 +08"
```